# Split type for frame

Tags: jasper-reports

Hi I am new to Jasper report and I am having a report with one text field and corresponding sub-report in the frame under detail band.Now I need to apply split type to prevent for the detail band, but I couldn't because I have subreport within detail band.Please assist me on this.Thanks in advance.

```xml
<detail>
        <band height="30">
            <frame>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="30" backcolor="#333333"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#9B64C8"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#9B64C8"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#9B64C8"/>
                </box>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="166" height="30" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    </reportElement>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#9BA66D"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#9BA66D"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#9BA66D"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#9BA66D"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Helvetica" size="9" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="CP1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{text1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="30"/>
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{subreport}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["sub.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

[image]

Second issue:
[image]

Comment: What is your current output? what is your excepted output?, what is the error?

Comment: I need to set Splittype Prevent to subreport report detailband.I can set and it's working perfectly.But at the same time text field is printing with blank space on it's right side.How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot?

Comment: Added screenshot.Look at the last row it has only the first field and remaining fields are from subreport.It is coming on the next page because of splittype I applied in subreport detail band.Now how to prevent the first field from printing?

Comment: I see you have same x and y on both textField and subreport, this seems strange... Where would you expect it to be printed?, have you tried setting isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="false" on the textField?

Comment: I tried to set subreport x value as 100 but it's printing from third column and isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="false" is not working.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you are really trying to achieve, the textField need's to be above/under the subreport?, next to subreport?, before subreport?

Comment: textfield needs to be left of the subreport

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is I need to print the textfield and its corresponding subreport.For example student and his semester marks,first text field is student name and remaining four fields in subreport is mark1,mark2,mark3,mark4 and the student can have 'n' number of semesters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100956/discussion-between-ganesh-kumar-s-r-and-petter-friberg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `textField` needs to be **next to** `subreport` and you need jasper report to try to print the record completely on 1 page.

1. Design the report correctly (move the subreport and give it the correct dimensions)

```xml
    <subreport>
       <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="166" y="0" width="334" height="30" uuid="e812a308-674c-41dc-be83-e872752c8d6d"/>
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{subreport}]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{absolutePath} + "sub.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
    </subreport>
```

The subreport should have correct pageWidth, columnWidth and margins

```xml
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subreport" pageWidth="334" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="332" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="775a7e35-9af8-4206-a155-b05a478c35b0">
```

2. Move the `splitType="prevent"` from subreport to main report.

This will need that your datasource is a [JRRewindableDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRRewindableDataSource.html), since jasper report will try to fill band in current page, but if it can not it will need to rewind and fill on next page. You need to implement the `moveFirst()` method in your datasource.

Comment: I used JRRewindableDataSource instead of JRDataSource and I set splitType="prevent" to main report detail band.It works perfectly.Thank you.

Comment: At last one issue,Column header is printing at page end even no row on detail band,next page also having columnheader with rows in detail band.I need to avoid column header from printing at page end.

Comment: Do you have only column header in last page (without no rows) or do you wan't column header only on first page?

Comment: Added second issue screenshot,On first page only header is coming on next page header with rows.I need to remove header on first page..

Comment: This is actually more complex than your first question, since you could have records on first page (if you did not overflow with prevent).... I probably would but a break in report, to force the table to start on next page... If you are not happy with answer try posting a new question with only this issue.

Comment: @GaneshkumarSR  Another possible solution could be a printWhenExpression with if is first page and the subreport contains more then x records do not print....